# javascript - Get filename and extension from FILE_URI in Ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I need some hint on how to get the name of a file, that has been picked/photographed by the cordova camera plugin. Here is the code, I have for getting a picture:

```
var options = {destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI};
options.sourceType = sourceType;
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (newURI) {
  imageFileURI = newURI;
  console.log('NATIVE_URI:\n' + imageFileURI);
  //I need to get the file name and extension here
  window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(imageFileURI, function (base64Image) {
    base64Data = base64Image;  
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('Error while converting to base64: ' + error);
  });
}, function (error) {
 console.log('Error while picking a photo: ' + error);
});
```

Is there a way, how can I get the file name and the extension, where I need it?
Thank you

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A67433` is what I get logged in console

Comment: I noticed that your app is build for Android platform, but you used in options `Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` which is for iOS. What happens using `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`? Have you already tried adding the option `saveToPhotoAlbum: true`?

Comment: You are right in some way. console output was from an Android device, but I am making an application for the iOS, too and I found out, that when I use `NATIVE_URI` I can determine the name of a file from the URI. I have the option `saveToPhotoAlbum` set to true, but somehow, it doesn't work. This doesn't bother me actually, as I don't know how this option should help me in finding out the name.

Comment: Hi, @NimeshkaSrimal unfortunately I cannot as I haven't tried your answer and thus haven't proven it works. Moreover, I am not working on this project anymore (as you can see, the question is 2.5 yrs old).

Answer (score 5):

var fileName = imageFileURI.substr(imageFileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

The above code to get the file name.

var fileExtension = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

this will get the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's too late to answer this question.

This is how I solved the exact issue. Problem is it gives you the file URI when the image is in phone memory, and a content:// url when it's from the external storage.

Solution is to use this plugin. [cordova-plugin-filepath](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath).

You can read the above github page for instructions. This is how I used it.

```
  window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(
    ImageURI, 
    function(imagePath){
      $(el).html(imagePath);
    }, 
    function(){
      alert('Could not retrieve the image path'); 
    });
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

- As beaver says, try FILE_URI
- It looks like you're trying to get an image in Base64, correct? If so, you can use the [ngCordova file](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) plugin and use readAsDataURL()
- If neither of these work, you can use [resolveLocalFileSystemURL](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file)

Comment: I explained in comment under beaver's post, why there is `NATIVE_URI`. To explain it more properly: my app should load an image from the phone's storage (or use camera to take one, that's why I decided to use for both actions the cordova camera plugin from ngCordova) and send it within a POST request to a server, where it should be processed. the 'should be processed' thing is based on the file's extension, as not every image extension is suitable. So, I get the photo's URI, and am able to send a POST with that URI, but I need to set the name of a file in the header, and that's my question.

Comment: The base64 encoding is needed, because i want to display that picture to the user before uploading, so in `ng-src` attribute of an `<img>` tag I use this base64 string. this is the only usage of the base64. On the other hand I am to try, whether I can send a post with the base64 image, but I am not sure.

Comment: And to your third advice, `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` sadly didn't work. No idea why. It goes to the error callback, but i dont know the fields of that error, so if I make `console.log(error)` it prints something like this `[object Object]`

Comment: I'm confused at your reponse. I use FILE_URI and this is an example of the result: ```file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160104_093602.jpg```. As you can see, it has the file extension. At this point you can use the URI as a file for the Cordova File plugin or whatever you need.

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A67433` still getting this with the `FILE_URI`. Can you please post your code?

Comment: `$cordovaCamera.getPicture({
 destinationType: $window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
 sourceType: $window.Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
 allowEdit: false,
 correctOrientation: true
});`

Comment: And the success callback please? I still can't find anything different in my code.

Comment: The success callback is given the URL as I posted before. If you want, you can zip up your project and put it somewhere where I can look at it. If you do, please message me directly instead of continuing the conversation here.

Comment: As I cannot see any way how to send a PM here, I am (sadly) commenting again. I think I found out, that FILE_URI returns different values depending on Android version. If I try on 6.0 I am getting proper URI that terminates with filename and extension. Although on 4.4 I am getting what I posted here :/ I feel sad, because I need to write ugly workarounds as I am supporting 4.4 also. So if you don't have any other advices I just thank you for all of those, you posted.